# Principle of FFT in multidimensional array

Tags: matlab, fft

How can one explain the principle of `fft` in a multidimensional array?

```
Y = fft(X)
```

If `X` is a multidimensional array, then `fft(X)` treats the values along the first array dimension whose size does not equal 1 as vectors and returns the Fourier transform of each vector.

I don't understand it very well.

```
X=[1 2 ; 3 4];

X(:,:,2)=[5 6 ; 7  8]
```

Comment: That code snippet doesn't involve `fft`.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Do you know what the Discrete Fourier Transform is? Do you know what the FFT algorithm does? Do you know how a matrix can be split into many vectors?

Comment: No I know the fast fourier transform but my problem is that the reusult of fftn and fft is differents. If you wan to aplly an fft in 3d matrix you shoul apply fft in x and y and z why fft apply in one dimension. what is the differnce ?

Comment: @kais: Yes, `fft` and `fftn` do different things. `fftn` applies the FFT along each dimension, whereas `fft` applies it only along one dimension. This is clearly documented. They both have their uses, even if you don't see the point of `fft` now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the 2D case for simplicity.

Given a 2D matrix of data, X, one can treat each row vector individually and perform a one-dimensional discrete Fourier transform. This will decompose each row into one dimensional frequency components. No attention is given to whether the rows of the matrix are correlated, and so every row of the output matrix will have some non-zero components.

Alternatively, using `fft2`, one can decompose X into its constituent two-dimensional frequency components. I find this easiest to think about in analogy with the DCT, where you can visualize the 2D basis easily
[image: 2D DCT basis functions]

With the 2D FFT, correlations between rows would affect the output of the FFT. It's possible a single 2D frequency component (which is more like a surface than a wave) could contain all the energy of the 2D FFT, and so the output matrix could be much sparser than when treating the rows individually.

This analogy can be continued in to n-dimensions, with higher dimensional frequency components potentially capturing the higher dimensional structure in your data.